# Scrolling on very long files (1M+ lines) on Emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I was wondering if besides the basic navigation commands:

```
C-p : Jump backwards one line.
C-n : Jump forward one line.
C-v : Jump forward one full screen.
M-v : Jump backwards one full screen.
M-a : Go to the previous paragraph beginnings.
M-e : Go to the next paragraph end.
M-g g: Jump to a specific line
```

emacs provides any commands to easily scroll thousands or millions of lines.

More specifically, I am looking for example for a command that I could use to move forward (or backwards) `1%` of the file (maybe a command that can be combined with `C-u` and can be used to scroll an arbitrary `%` of the file?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The commands `beginning-of-buffer` (`C-home` or `M-<`) and `end-of-buffer` (`C-end` or `M->`) take a numeric argument. If the argument is *N*, then the command takes you *N*/10 of the way. (With some rounding: these commands take you to the beginning of a line.) For example, `M-1 M->` goes to the 90% position in the buffer, i.e. around line 900000 in a million-line buffer.

For more precise control, you can scroll to the end, note the line number, and use `M-g g` (`goto-line`) to reach a particular line number, e.g. `ESC 9 0 0 0 ESC g g` to go to line 9000.

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

A fast way to navigate is to use incremental search (`C-s`) and its variants.

I wonder if `occur` can be useful for navigating between matches on such large files. It shows a separate window with all occurrences of a match regexp, which you can navigate with `M-g n` and `M-g p`.

For jumping to percentage of buffer, http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/basic-edit-toolkit.el has a function for this:

```
(defun goto-percent (percent)
  "Goto PERCENT of buffer."
  (interactive "nGoto percent: ")
  (goto-char (/ (* percent (point-max)) 100)))
```

`forward-paragraph` and `backward-paragraph` may also be useful for fast navigation, depending on the file structure (bound to `M-}` and `M-{`).

Answer (score 2):

```
C-u PERCENT M-x View-goto-percent
```

moves the cursor `PERCENT` of the way through of buffer.